# i am using ffmpeg library API to record camera stream in to mp file, working with one camera but throwing an error if more than one camera connected

Tags: video, ffmpeg

using ffmpeg API to record AV stream in to mp4 file for multiple cameras using multiple threads, but it is working with single camera connected, but if we connect more than 2 camera and try to record AV stream of both the camera streams in respected mp4 files seperately it is throwing an error ("Error Muxing Packet");
could you please provide and solution or answer for this..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to try to solve your own problem first. Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Deceloped the code to record live video stream of camera using FFMPEG library APIs. Developed the code with proper sequence of APIs to be used to record live video in MP4 file. Connected the one camera, it is recording properly if we connect 2 cameras, it is started recording in mp4 file but immediately it is stopped recording while writing av_interleaved_write_frame(); and throwing an error saying "Error while muxing the packet" by using this function.

Comment: Taking the reference of the FFMPEG muxing code to develop the recorder which is provided in the path: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/remuxing.c. creating 2 threads to record 2 camera live video stream in my recorder process